# Script adds 3 comma's into ".html" method

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my word game there is a scoring system which adds each correct word spelt.

I start by setting it to "0" in the "newGame" function like this

```
$('.score').html("0/" + completionNumber);
```

Completion number is the amount completed so this should show "0/0", which it does when I run locally on a browser. But for some reason it displays "0/,,,0" when I run it on the server and I don't know why.

When the correct word is spelt I add the new score with this line

```
$('.score').html(score.right + "/" + completionNumber).show();
```

And reset the score in "resetGame" function like this

```
$('.score').html("");
```

Can anyone help me or tell me if this has happened to them before?

EDIT**

Here is the script file in a fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/Z2JtD/

Comment: Can you log `completionNumber` and see if that's the problem? It's probably the way you're adding it up... Although, if it runs fine locally.......

Comment: We're going to need some more code than this.

Comment: does console.log( completionNumber ); show correct value ..?

Comment: I can give you the script file? The css animations and styles will not work in fiddle @RickKuipers

Comment: I'd say show us every line that has $('.score').html() or completionNumber, that should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes completionNumber does show the correct value @Sudhir

Comment: Well I have given you all the lines with $('.score').html() in. Check edit for the lines with completion number in. @RickKuipers

Comment: Throwing the whole code isn't really helpful. Please also add your HTML in the fiddle so the problem can be reproduced..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a quick check of your script and saw `completionNumber = [];`  I see that array is a global, and is accessed and set several times throughout the script.  What's happening, at some point, is your array looks like

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, 0]
```

So when it prints, it displays as

```
0/,,,0
```

I would consider an app re-structure to only set those globals after proper validation.

Comment: That makes sense. Would it be better to set the variables I have as locals instead of globals? @Stephan